# iTunes freezes during startup ("updating library") after updating Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, itunes, osx-lion

I have Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2, and after I made my last OS updates, iTunes (10.5.2) freezes at the "updating library" step.

It has being doing that for two days now, and it is not working yet, even after restarting the computer.

Any recommendations to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if the solutions [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3566640?start=0&tstart=0) work out for you.

This includes the [following post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17032017#17032017):

> I pressed shift-option-command and clicked on iTunes in the dock. iTunes started in safe mode, it said 'iTunes is starting in safe mode and any visual add ons will be disabled" clicked OK and it started up and went throught the library update with no problems.

Also, if you don't really need your library, you can try to move the *~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl* file away temporarily, and then try to restart iTunes with a fresh library.